# Dynamically add more fields/remove last field in a form

Tags: ajax, forms

What I want to achieve is to build a form, which contains buttons "add one more field" and "remove last field" that would do exactly this - add a field dynamically to my form or remove the last one. I have done this in Drupal, but am not sure how exactly to achieve this in WordPress.
My basic logic is to use ajax to insert new fields dynamically or remove the last one. Is there something like Form API in Wordpress (I tried to search but without success) that will me my task easier to achieve?

Comment: When you say `form` do you mean like a contact form? Or do you mean meta boxes (that hold post data/information)? If you mean like a contact form, I strongly recommend Gravity Forms: http://www.gravityforms.com/